# Representing a Foreign Key as some other value in a WPF StackPanel GridViewColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a StackPanel that sets its GridColumns with the Columns of the Entity's Properties / Table Columnms. A lot of the columns are Foreign Keys from other tables. A brief example below shows once such Foreign key - CustomerID.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
    <Label Content="Tests to Run" FontWeight="Bold" x:Name="TestsToRunLabel"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedTechnician.Tests}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTest}" x:Name="AvailableTestsListView" Height="140">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Id" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Test" Width="auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CustomerId}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

As expected this simply shows the integer value associated with the key and not some "user readable" value such as a Customer Name or some other useful value.

If its possible, how can I "cast" or represent a Foreign Key like CustomerId to display some other value in the Customer table?

This would essentially get the key as it does now and reach through to the Customer table and grab something like Customer.Name as its representative property in my StackPanel.

**Things to note:**

Test and Customer are Code-First entities. I am also using MVVM so if this is something I need to manipulate in a ViewModel rather than in the XAML, please let me know.

Comment: From your code, it seems like you are binding your "Test" column to a property on your viewmodel called "CustomerId". If you want to bind to "CustomerName" instead, you will need to define this property on your viewmodel and manually handle population of this data. You could include a Customer object on your parent viewmodel and use a query to retrieve the required Customer object based on your CustomerId.

Comment: @failedprogramming can elaborate on what you mean by "include a Customer object on my parent viewmodel"? As a property? instantiate it as a concrete object? Feel free to post an answer to the question.

Comment: In my applications, I use a single Window to show content. My various screens are split up into UserControls and I have a WorkspaceViewModel Class for each UserControl. If we use your situation as an example, I would probably have a UserControl that would show "Test". The TestWorkspaceViewModel Class that drives that UserControl would have your foreign key "CustomerId". I would create a CustomerViewModel class and include it as a property in the TestWorkspaceViewModel. It would be populated with code similar to that in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve my own problem, I created a set of "display-only" properties on my business model object that simply performs a LINQ query to return a more meaningful attribute/property/column:

```
public string CustomerName
{
    get
    {
        var db = new Context();

        var customer = db.Customers.Find(CustomerId);
        _customerName = customer.Name;

        return _customerName;
    }
}
```

Comment: @failedprogramming your comment certainly got me thinking in the right direction. thanks.

Comment: No worries at all. One little thing which you might already know. It would be useful to wrap your context in a using statement to help dispose of it, and also check that customer is not null before assigning _customerName.